# How to compare values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
times = {'personA': [9,10,11,15,16,18,19],'personB': [12,14,15,16,19]}
```

I am trying to find times that these two people are available. These are the 'blocked' times two people are unavailable. So 9,10,11 would be 9am-11am, 15,16 would be 3pm-4pm and so on.
I want to find out all the numbers from 1-24 where both people are available. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: have you tried anything to solve it? also you are missing a closing `]` in `personB`

Comment: You can use sets and check their union to quickly find all the blocked times for at least one of the parties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use sets instead of lists

e.g.

```
>>> times = {'personA': {9,10,11,15,16,18,19},'personB': {12,14,15,16,19}}
>>> hours = set(range(1,25))
>>> both = hours - (times['personA'] | times['personB'])
>>> both
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}
```

Comment: The OP wanted to know how to find the times they were both available. These are the times that they are unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

```
times = {'personA': [9,10,11,15,16,18,19],'personB': [12,14,15,16,19]}
# Just a set with all 24 hours because
whole_day = {x for x in range(25)}

# Getting available time for both since it's what we need in fact, not busy time
free_times = {key: whole_day - set(value) for key, value in times.items()}

# Getting intersection of those free hours -> result
common_free_time = free_times['personA'] & free_times['personB']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
times = {'personA': [9,10,11,15,16,18,19],'personB': [12,14,15,16,19]}
combined = times['personA'] + times['personB']
all_times = [i for i in range(1, 25)]
result = [x for x in all_times if x not in combined]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd create a set of all the available times, and remove all the slots either person is not available from it:

```
available = set(range(12,25))
for v in times.values():
    available = available - set(v)
```

Comment: @KingRadical I loop over all the lists in the dictionary and remove them **all** from the available times. Any time that has at least one person not available will be removed from the result.

Comment: indeed, I was too hasty